# How to assign/update roles to a Google Serivce Account in python?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-api-python-client, google-iam

I'm using the [google api python client](https://pypi.org/project/google-api-python-client/) to create a service account and associate it with some Google existing roles. In particular I'd like to associate with the Google Storage 'objectAdmin' role.

Reading from the documentation this could be feasible with the following script:

```py
def create_service_account(project_id, account_id, display_name):
    """Creates a service account."""

    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        filename=os.getenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'),
        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])

    service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        'iam', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

    my_service_account = service.projects().serviceAccounts().create(
        name=f'projects/{project_id}',
        body={
            'accountId': account_id,
            'serviceAccount': {
                'displayName': display_name
            }
        }).execute()
    return my_service_account


def assign_role(project_id, unique_id, email):
    """Assign role to a service account."""

    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        filename=os.getenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'),
        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])

    service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        'iam', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

    policy = service.projects().serviceAccounts().setIamPolicy(
        resource=f'projects/{project_id}/serviceAccounts/{unique_id}',
        body={
            'policy': {
                'version': 3,
                "bindings": [
                    {
                        "role": f"roles/storage.objectAdmin",
                        "condition": {
                            "title": "TenantSpace",
                            "expression": f'resource.type == "storage.googleapis.com/Object" && resource.name.startsWith("projects/{project_id}/buckets/demo/")',
                        }
                    }
                ],
            }
        }
    ).execute()
    return policy

service_account = create_service_account(
        project_id='XXXX',
        account_id='test-name-sa',
        display_name='TestNameServiceAccount'
)
policy = assign_role(
        project_id='XXXX',
        unique_id=service_account['uniqueId'],
        email=service_account['email']
)
```

While the service account is correctly created, I cannot proceed further since the `assign_role` function fails with the following message:

> Role roles/storage.objectAdmin is not supported for this resource

I'm referring to this documentation https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/setIamPolicy#examples but since I'm doing something wrong for sure, what's the correct way in achieving this task?

Answer (score 2):

As @John Hanley said, the posted snippet is trying to create a binding on the service account as a resource, which is not allowed by design. What I had to do was set a new IAM policy **project wise** and not resource wise.

This means to **get** the current IAM policy, **modify** the bindings appending the new rule (with optionally the conditions) and finally **set** the modified policy.

**!!! CAUTION !!!**: setting the IAM policy project wise could lock you out of the project so always try it first on a test project you don't care about (that you can delete and recreate).

In this snippet the `crm_service` and the `iam_service` are pre-created with:

```py
    def __init__(self):
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            filename=os.getenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'),
            scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'],
        )
        self.iam_service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
            'iam', 'v1', credentials=credentials,
        )
        self.crm_service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
            'cloudresourcemanager', 'v1', credentials=credentials,
        )
```

```py
    def set_policy(self, project_id, policy):
        """Sets IAM policy for a project."""

        policy = (
            self.crm_service.projects()
            .setIamPolicy(resource=project_id, body={'policy': policy})
            .execute()
        )
        return policy

    def get_policy(self, project_id, version=3):
        """Gets IAM policy for a project."""

        policy = (
            self.crm_service.projects()
            .getIamPolicy(
                resource=project_id,
                body={'options': {'requestedPolicyVersion': version}},
            )
            .execute()
        )
        return policy

    def modify_policy_add_role(self, project_id, role, member, condition=None):
        """Adds a new role binding to a policy."""

        policy = self.get_policy(project_id)

        binding = None
        for b in policy['bindings']:
            if b['role'] == role:
                binding = b
                break
        if binding is not None:
            binding['members'].append(member)
        else:
            policy['version'] = 3
            binding = {
                'role': role,
                'members': [member],
            }
            if condition is not None:
                binding['condition'] = condition
            policy['bindings'].append(binding)

        return self.set_policy(project_id, policy)

new_conditions = {
            'title': 'Tenant bucket access control',
            'expression': f'resource.type == "storage.googleapis.com/Object" && resource.name.startsWith("projects/{YOUR_PROJECT_ID}/buckets/bucket_name/")',
}
modify_policy_add_role(
            project_id=YOUR_PROJECT_ID,
            role='roles/storage.objectCreator', # new role to add
            member=f'serviceAccount:{YOUR_SA_EMAIL}',
            condition=new_conditions, # optionally a set of conditions
)
```

Comment: This is a good answer that will help others. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you are using the service account as a resource. Service accounts do not provide storage, therefore, you cannot add a storage-related IAM role.

If your goal is to grant users of the service account permissions to Cloud Storage, then you must add an IAM policy binding to the project or the Cloud Storage resource (bucket, object).

Comment: I see, so this must be related to the two sides of Service Accounts (principles and resources). Would you mind providing some references or even better a code snippet for sake of completion to the question context?

Comment: @Barnercart - There are numerous examples of modifying a project's IAM policy bindings. Google has them in their examples section for the SDKs and there are many tutorials on the Internet. You posted a problem. I answered why your solution will not work.

Comment: @Barnercart - One important tip: do not test your code on a project that you care about. It is very easy to lock yourself out of a project by overwriting the policy. Only Google support can recover your access from that problem. Create a throw-away project and test with that. When you have an issue, delete the project and create another one.

Comment: Sadly it may have just happened @John Hanley

Comment: @Barnercart - if that was for an important project, open a Google Cloud support ticket now. Collect your details such as Project Number, account owner email address, etc.